# Is the size of docker image or docker container impact the creation time of a container

Tags: image, docker, containers

Is the size of docker image or docker container impact the creation time of a container ?
How can i calculate the time of container creation?

Comment: Are you talking about the build time of an image (depending on the size of the build context) or the startup time of a container?

Comment: the creation time of a container from a pre-built image

Comment: You can measure this fairly straightforwardly: containers don't have independent clocks from their host and _e.g._ **time**(1) will return consistent times in both places.

Comment: So i can measure the time using python module time *** start = time.time()
 container = client.containers.run("image-name", detach=True)
 end = time.time()-****